# How to get script URL with RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

When simply loading your script with a `<script />` tag, you can retrieve the script URL like this:

```
var scriptURL = Array.prototype.pop.call (       // get the last...
        document.getElementsByTagName ('script') // ...script tag on the page...
    ).src.split ('?') [0];                       // ...take 'src' attribute...
                                                 // ...and strip the query string
```

This is a bit of a hack, but can be very useful sometimes, for a number of reasons (e.g., when there are other resource files script relies on and you don't want to hardcode the path). It works because at the time of execution the last `<script />` tag existing on the page is your script.

I'm not sure if that is so when loading scripts with **RequireJS**. Is there a similar way in **RequireJS** to retrieve the script URL from inside the module definition?

Answer (score 9):

You can require the `module` module, which commonly used to pass the special [`config`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-moduleconfig) settings:

```
define(['module'], function (module) {
  console.log(module)
}
```

This will give you an object holding the id and the uri to the module

Answer (score 1):

To get the URL of current module you can use the below script in requirejs.

```
define([module/hello], function (hello) {
    var currentUrl = location.href;
    var moduleUrl = url+require.toUrl("module/hello.js");
    alert(moduleUrl);
});
```